# Changing the Logic Board on the Macbook, does it changes the serial number?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, logicboard, logic, serial-number

I have changed the Logic Board from my Macbook, is there any chance that the serial number is another different one from the original Macbook?
I really need help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Serial numbers are hard coded / written to Apple main board / logic boards. Unless you use a service tool, you would end up with a new serial after the swap.